# LTSP keeping sessions active whilst turning off thin clients

Tags: ubuntu, thin-client, ltsp

I'm using LTSP on a Ubuntu 10.04 64bit box with 8 thin clients.

I would like to save power by automatically turning off the thin clients at night, but I would like to have the ability to resume the staff's session in the morning.

Is it possible to keep a session running whilst turning off the LTSP thin client and resuming that session when you power up the thin client the next time?

Could this work if you login to another thin client in the morning and resume your session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked, this was NOT possible.

In a modern LTSP environment, the sessions are associated with an SSH connection. If you are powering off the terminals, the SSH connection will have to be re-negotiated.

If the old session's processes are still there and have not been removed, the users will likely see problems with the Gnome.

In our Ubuntu 9.10 environment,we had problems with users sessions being dropped and thus unable to log back in. To removing those processes that were hanging around, we ended up using the 'XExit' script from the LTSP Developer Community on IRC.

Comment: What about using something like 'xpra' which is like screen for GUI apps?

Comment: If the LTSP folks were to built that capability in, that may work. But I don't think one could get it going without hacking on the LTSP packages. It appears Xpra does not use standard X forwarding and uses its own window manager.